# zeon java library is not catching exceptions

Tags: java, sftp

Hi I´m implementing a sftp client using Zeon library and it works fine. The problem starts when I test it for failures here is my code:

```
int status = 0;
try {
    SFTPClient sftpClient = new SFTPClient(host, username, password);
    status = sftpClient.sendFolder(sendingFolder, destFolder, new BatchTransferProgressDefault());

    System.out.println("FileTransferStatus.SUCCESS: " + FileTransferStatus.SUCCESS);
    System.out.println("status: " + status);
}catch (FileTransferException e){
    LOGGER.error(e);
}catch (Exception e2){
    LOGGER.error(e2);
}
```

So I put a wrong host, username and password and the status flag still returns true even tough my console shows an exception and it doesn´t enter into my exception.

Does anyone knows how to force the zeon libraries into entering into my exception block??
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but is the status == false before entering the try block?

Comment: @sdasdadas if the status is `true` after the block and an Exception is logged, than it can only have been `true` before entering the block.

Comment: @linker85 what do you mean by _it doesn´t enter into my exception_? You say it's on the console, is that where `LOGGER` writes it? If an Exception occurs in the code you posted, than the value of `status` won't change in the `try/catch` block.

Comment: Then that would suggest that following the status flag is completely irrelevant and that an exception is being thrown and only being logged.

Comment: it trows a FileTransferException but it doesn´t enter into the catch blocks

Comment: Have you added System.out.println in the exception block?

Comment: @linker85 how do you know the `catch` block is not entered if a `FileTransferException` is thrown??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to be a bug of the library i will have to look for a different library. It´s shame because it was easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that this is probably happening:

```
boolean status = true;
// ... status flag doesn't ever get set to false ...
try {
    SFTPClient sftpClient = new SFTPClient(host, username, password);
    // Your error is thrown before you get this far.
    status = sftpClient.sendFolder(sendingFolder, destFolder, new BatchTransferProgressDefault());
    System.out.println("FileTransferStatus.SUCCESS: " + FileTransferStatus.SUCCESS);
    System.out.println("status: " + status);
} catch (FileTransferException e){
    // The error is logged which means you'll only see it wherever you log it.
    LOGGER.error(e);
} catch (Exception e2){
    LOGGER.error(e2);
}
```

Comment: yeah something alike althoug this library returns int

Comment: Either way - the point is that it actually IS throwing an exception and you're just logging it. Put a System.out.println in your catch blocks and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: i change Logger for e.printstracktrace() but it still doesn´t want to catch the error

Comment: Did you change both LOGGERS to print the stack trace? If so, I was wrong then - does it print out FileTransferStatus.SUCCESS?

Comment: yep even tough it threw an exception it still tells me that it did a succesfull transfer which it´s a lie.

Comment: I only have one more suggestion: set status = 50 (or any random number) before this code and then print it out right before you print "FileTransferStatus.SUCCESS...". Does it change?

Comment: i´m starting to believe that zeon is handling the exceptions by itself and it´s returning success always